# Unexpected token (8:8) while parsing file

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using `antd` and I wanna use its [registration Form](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register) in my project.

**Note**: Before adding this component my project (registration.js) was working correctly and I've just copied and pasted the antd component.

Here is my `registration.js` file:

```
import { Form, Input, Tooltip, Icon, Cascader, Select, Row, Col, Checkbox, Button, AutoComplete } from 'antd';

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;
const AutoCompleteOption = AutoComplete.Option;

class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
    autoCompleteResult: [],
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }

  handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value });
  }

  compareToFirstPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && value !== form.getFieldValue('password')) {
      callback('Two passwords that you enter is inconsistent!');
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  validateToNextPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const form = this.props.form;
    if (value && this.state.confirmDirty) {
      form.validateFields(['confirm'], { force: true });
    }
    callback();
  }

  handleWebsiteChange = (value) => {
    let autoCompleteResult;
    if (!value) {
      autoCompleteResult = [];
    } else {
      autoCompleteResult = ['.com', '.org', '.net'].map(domain => `${value}${domain}`);
    }
    this.setState({ autoCompleteResult });
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const { autoCompleteResult } = this.state;

    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 8 },
      },
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 16 },
      },
    };
    const tailFormItemLayout = {
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: {
          span: 24,
          offset: 0,
        },
        sm: {
          span: 16,
          offset: 8,
        },
      },
    };
    const prefixSelector = getFieldDecorator('prefix', {
      initialValue: '86',
    })(
      <Select style={{ width: 70 }}>
        <Option value="86">+86</Option>
        <Option value="87">+87</Option>
      </Select>
    );

    const websiteOptions = autoCompleteResult.map(website => (
      <AutoCompleteOption key={website}>{website}</AutoCompleteOption>
    ));

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="E-mail"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('email', {
            rules: [{
              type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
            }, {
              required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
            }],
          })(
            <Input />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Password"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please input your password!',
            }, {
              validator: this.validateToNextPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Confirm Password"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('confirm', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please confirm your password!',
            }, {
              validator: this.compareToFirstPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" onBlur={this.handleConfirmBlur} />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label={(
            <span>
              Nickname&nbsp;
              <Tooltip title="What do you want others to call you?">
                <Icon type="question-circle-o" />
              </Tooltip>
            </span>
          )}
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('nickname', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your nickname!', whitespace: true }],
          })(
            <Input />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Habitual Residence"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('residence', {
            initialValue: ['zhejiang', 'hangzhou', 'xihu'],
            rules: [{ type: 'array', required: true, message: 'Please select your habitual residence!' }],
          })(
            <Cascader options={residences} />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Phone Number"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('phone', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your phone number!' }],
          })(
            <Input addonBefore={prefixSelector} style={{ width: '100%' }} />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Website"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('website', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input website!' }],
          })(
            <AutoComplete
              dataSource={websiteOptions}
              onChange={this.handleWebsiteChange}
              placeholder="website"
            >
              <Input />
            </AutoComplete>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Captcha"
          extra="We must make sure that your are a human."
        >
          <Row gutter={8}>
            <Col span={12}>
              {getFieldDecorator('captcha', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input the captcha you got!' }],
              })(
                <Input />
              )}
            </Col>
            <Col span={12}>
              <Button>Get captcha</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem {...tailFormItemLayout}>
          {getFieldDecorator('agreement', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
          })(
            <Checkbox>I have read the <a href="">agreement</a></Checkbox>
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem {...tailFormItemLayout}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Register</Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedRegistrationForm = Form.create()(RegistrationForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedRegistrationForm />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

And this is my `index.html` file:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I face with this error in my `registration.js` file:

`Unexpected token (8:8) while parsing file`

Line 8 refers to where we have `state = {`, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) (`state = ...`) is not a part of the language yet, so you need a Babel plugin or preset for it.

Comment: [installed package](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00929/qxwau4suan2q.png "package is already installed") I have already installed this package, but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have you added it to your babel config?

Comment: [Here is my gulp config](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00929/a8l6x1ug19o6.png "gulp config")

Comment: You haven't added the plugin to the config. Write `{presets: ['es2015', 'react'], plugins: ['transform-class-properties']}`

Comment: [I have no idea](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00929/4bm2ixqds1xq.png "the plugin have been added")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not using the right transpilers.

Declaring global variables in classes like your `state = { ... }` is only possible with ES7 (I believe). You are probably using a ES6 transpiler.

One fix would be changing your syntax to ES6. So you would have to declare you state like this:

```
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { ... };
    }

    // ...
}
```

ES6 also doesn't support declaring class methods with arrow syntax (`myMethod = () => { ... }`). You would have to change all of your methods to `myMethod() { ... }`

Another fix would be to download the right presets so babel (I'm guessing you are using babel) can transpile your ES7 syntax.

Comment: [I have added the plugin to transform ES7 to ES6](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00929/4bm2ixqds1xq.png "plugins") but it still doesn't work

Comment: Well, I have never used that plugin - I'm still using ES6 - so can't help you there. I would go with the refactor solution hehe

Comment: After refactoring, I face with this error in console of Chrome. `Uncaught ReferenceError: Form is not defined`

Comment: This is weird.. If the code you posted is right, Form IS defined.. maybe double check a typo?

Comment: I have just copied the code in the ant.design website